# Data Null on Ajax Post

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning about ajax to make my life a little easier moving forward. I was able to follow an example and get a constant array to POST to my controller normally.

Now that I am trying to get data from an html form, I get a null array in my controller.

using `.serialize()` I get `[0] = "item=teststring1&item=teststring2"`

using `.serializeArray()` I get an array of length 2 (the correct size), with both values null.

I've read about the issues with `serializeArray()` and how it requires certain tags.

How can I resolve the issue of a null array posting to my controller?

JS

```
// #EditDate is form id
var data = $('#EditDate').serializeArray();  

        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "TrainingDates")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {'dates' : data},
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success" + result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("failure" + result);
                }
        });

        $(element).val('Edit');
```

HTML

```
@model List<string>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dates";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TrainingDates", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "EditDate", @class = "collapse" }))
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:inherit" onclick="editable('@item', this)" value="Edit">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item, new { @id = item, name = item, @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<string> dates)
{
        if(dates != null)
        {
            var json = new { success = true };
            return Json(json);
        }
        return Json(false);
 }
```

Comment: I would expect `$('#EditDate').serializeArray()` to be `$('#EditDate input').serializeArray()`

Comment: @Steve why? The form ID is EditDate

Comment: Right but to send specifically the textboxes you may want to select _only_ the textboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action method parameter is a list of strings. So basically for model binding to properly work, you should be sending an array like this from your ajax call

```
["12-12-2011","10-10-2011"]
```

Your current code uses jquery `serializeArray` method which will create an array of items,each with `name` and `value` properties. So basically your code is sending something like this in the ajax request.

```
dates[0][name]:item
dates[0][value]:12-12-2011
dates[1][name]:item
dates[1][value]:10-10-2011
```

The default model binder cannot map this to a list of strings.

All you need to do is, sending a an array of string(or dates) to server. You may simply use the jQuery map method to create an array from the input field values.

This should work.

```
var d = $.map($("[name='item']"), function(v, k) {
    return v.value;
});              

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "TrainingDates")',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(d),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("success" , result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("failure" + result);
    }
});
```

I would also strongly advise to use the correct datatype. If you are dealing with dates, why not use `DateTime` class instead of `string` ? DateTime class was created to handle usecases like these :)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<DateTime> dates)
{
  // to do  : return something
}
```

Comment: DateTime will be used absolutely. String was just a base starting point due to most examples using strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted data does not match the variable name and data type in your controller.
make these minor adjustments:
Javascript - remove `dataType: "json"` and pass data as form-url-encoded directly `data: $('#EditDate').serializeArray()`. No need to convert to JSON format.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "TrainingDates")',
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#EditDate').serializeArray(),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success" + result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("failure" + result);
                }
        });
```

Controller - change variable name "dates" to "item" to matched your JavaScript ajax call.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<string> item)
{
        if(item != null)
        {
            var json = new { success = true };
            return Json(json);
        }
        return Json(false);
 }
```